# Javascript read directory content

Tags: javascript, directory

Learning javascript. I'm want to read a folder content with javascript. Tried different examples. But I didn't.

Code:

```
var $directories=[];
var $images = [];
var $dirname="img";
$dh = opendir($dirname);
while( !($file = readdir($dh))=== false )
{
    if (is_dir("$dirname/$file"))
    {
        if ($file!='.' && $file!='..')
        array_push($directories,$file);
    }    
    else
         array_push($images, $file);
}
closedir($dh);
```

Taking Uncaught ReferenceError: opendir is not defined error message.

How can I fix it?

Thanks..

Sorry for the question.

Comment: this looks more like php than JavaScript to me

Comment: You are trying to use PHP syntax in a Javascript env. Clearly PHP functions are `not defined`.

Comment: Realy. I found it javascript tutorial. Sorry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but this code is **PHP** Not **Javascript**....